# Using selection sort - java deck of cards

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am going to start with the code that I have.

```
public class DeckOfCards2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] deck = new int[52];
    String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
    String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    // Initialize cards
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
      deck[i] = i;
    }

    // Shuffle the cards
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
      int index = (int)(Math.random() * deck.length);
      int temp = deck[i];
      deck[i] = deck[index];
      deck[index] = temp;
    }

    // Display the all the cards
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
      String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
      String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];
      System.out.println( rank + " of " + suit);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what I'm trying to do and don't know how to do it. I am a beginner. I need help please:

- Create a array of random card. (already done)
- Output this array in a formatted print statement using a toString
  method (unsorted).(not done yet but I do know how to get this part.)
- Use the selection sort to sort your array.(don't know how.)
- Output a sorted array using the toString method.  Ascending
  alphabetical order: clubs (lowest), followed by diamonds, hearts, and
  spades (highest). (don't know how to get this order to print)This ranking is used in the game of bridge.
- Also print out the number iterations. (easy for me to put in)

Comment: We can't do all your homework for you. These are pretty simplistic things to accomplish with your own knowledge. If you get stuck on a _Specific_ thing, then come back and ask here. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

For the **Selection Sort** algorithm search the `Google` which has a lot of articles and examples:

- [Selection Sort](https://google.com/search?q=selection+sort+java)
- http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/selection-sort/
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/selection_sort_algorithm.htm
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/selection_sort_program_in_c.htm

Start with simple examples to understand the algorithm. Then use it for your task. 
The examples use numbers and compare with `<`, `>` operators. But for cards you could create another method which whould compare two cards by their names:

```
Ace of Clubs < 2 of Clubs
6 of Hearts < 3 of Spades
```

So within the same suit just compare indexes of `ranks` array. For different suits compare indexes of `suits` array. The arrays must be presorted before it. So the `suits` array should be:

```
String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
```

So the comparison for the previous example would be:

```
Ace of Clubs < 2 of Clubs  =>  // because ranks[0] < ranks[1] and 0 < 1, the suit doesn't matter
6 of Hearts < 3 of Spades  =>  // because suits[2] < suits[3] and 2 < 3, the rank doesn't matter
```

Hope this will help in your research.

Comment: So both arrays should be in order?

Comment: Yes. The `suits` array can be ordered during runtime if you need ascending or descending alphabetical order of the suits. But I guess for the `ranks` it should be sorted manually before the operations. Because you have to explain the program that **Ace < 3** and **Jack < Queen**...

Comment: The order that is supposed to be is Ace of Spades to Ace of Clubs descending in letter order for the suit and so on with the rest all the way down to 2. I was able to find a little bit but now it has it grouped together by the suit from A - 2 of that suit. I can't seem to figure out how to keep the rank together but order the suits of the cards.

Comment: I guess with the 1-dimensional `deck` array it's hard to sort. I suppose you'll have something like `deck = {3, 0, 2, 46, 21, ...}` and will need to sort it by some condition. But from it you cannot know which card is `deck[21]` because you have 2 dimensions (ranks, suits). So try to create an array `int[][] deck = new int[52][2]` and fill it with corresponding ranks and suits like `deck[0][0] = suits[0]; deck[0][1] = ranks[0]` will be **Ace of Spades**. Then fit the sorting algorithm to this 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Dealer {

public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        for (Suits s : Suits.values()) {
        for (Cards r : Cards.values()) {
             Card value = new Card(s,r);
             cards.add(value);
        }  
    }
    shuffle(cards);
    present(cards);
    System.out.println();
    cards = selectionSort(cards);
    present(cards);
}
private static void shuffle(ArrayList<Card> list){
     Collections.shuffle(list);
}
private static void present(ArrayList<Card> list){
    int count = 0;
    for (Card c : list){
        count++;
        System.out.println(c.toString());
    }
}
private static ArrayList<Card> selectionSort(ArrayList<Card> list){
    int min;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        count++;
        // Assume first element is min
        min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(j).Get() < list.get(min).Get()) {
                min = j;



}
    }

if(min != i){
    final Card temp = list.get(i);
    list.set(i,list.get(min));
    list.set(min,temp);
}

  //  System.out.println(list.get(i));// I print the in ascending order
}
System.out.println("================================== Sorted Deck Below =========================================================");
System.out.println("It took "+count+" iterations to sort this deck using selection sort.");
System.out.println();
return list;

}

private static ArrayList<Card> InsertionSort(ArrayList<Card> list){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Card temp = list.get(i);
        int j;
        for(j = i-1;j>=0&&temp.Get()<list.get(j).Get(); j--){
            list.set(j+1,list.get(j));
        }
       list.set(j+1,temp); 
       count ++;
    }
    System.out.println("================================== Sorted Deck Below =========================================================");
    System.out.println("It took "+count+" iterations to sort this deck using insertion sort.");
    System.out.println();
    return list;
}

public static ArrayList<Card> mergeSort(ArrayList<Card> list){
        if (list.size() ==1){
            return list;
        }
        else {
           int mid= list.size()/2;
           ArrayList<Card> left= new ArrayList<Card>(mid);
           ArrayList<Card> right=new ArrayList<Card>(list.size()-mid);



for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
           left.add(list.get(i));
       }







for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-mid; i++) {
           right.add(list.get(i));
       } 



left=mergeSort(left); 
   right=mergeSort(right);
   merge(left,right,list);
}
return list;

}


public static void merge (ArrayList<Card>left,ArrayList<Card>right,ArrayList<Card>list){
        int i1=0;// left Index
        int i2=0;// right Index
        int ListIndex=0;



for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (i2>=right.size() || (i1<left.size() && (right.get(i)>=left.get(i)))) 
        {
            list.set(ListIndex,left.get(i1));
            ListIndex++;
        }
        else {
            list.set(ListIndex, right.get(i2));
            ListIndex++;
        }
    }

}

}
```

===========================================================================

```
// Created enums
enum Cards{
   Ace,King,Queen,Jack,Ten,Nine,Eight,Seven,Six,Five,Four,Three,Two
}

enum Suits{
    Spades,
    Hearts,
    Diamonds,
    Clubs
}

public class Card{

 private Suits suit;
 private Cards card;

public Card(Suits suit, Cards card){


this.suit = suit;
    this.card = card;
}

public int Get(){
     return (suit.ordinal())+card.ordinal()*4;
}

public String toString(){


  return card.toString()+" of " +suit.toString();
    }
}
```

This is what I have know after I was asking some of my friends and they said try ArrayList of Object Card which I believe now is personally harder because of the Merge Sort that I know doesn't work but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it with ArrayList.